# Pyo - outputting to multiple audio channels

Tags: python, pyo

I'm using Pyo to generate sounds and have been having issues outputting the audio to more than one channel.

I've looked through the documentation and can't seem to find a method of sending the output to more than one channel at a time. For example you can specify

```
sines[n].out(chnl = 0)
```

or

```
sines[n].out(chnl = 1)
```

And this will output it to either the left or right channel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that by simply duplicating by Sine and ADSR object to have them be two separate objects and simply recording them both at the same time to each respective channel was the solution.

Comment: Do you have some code how you did it in the end?
How did you copy the Sine and whats the role of the ADSR object?
I'm stuck at the same point right now.

Comment: Didn't see this till now, I honestly have no clue as to why it requires this. What I assumed was you could make a single Sine and ADSR envelope and just output it to both channels, but from what I remember this didn't work so I tested various things. What I know is this solved my issue.